# Linux service stops logging

Tags: python, linux, service, systemd-journald

I have a service running. The service invokes a long running python script which "prints" some status messages. I can see these status messages with `journalctl -u myservice.service`. But after about 6 hours I am no longer able to see new outputs from the service.

If I run `systemctl status myservice.service`. I can tell that service is still running.

I suspected it had to do something with the logging, so I reduced the time intervall of the log output from once per minute to once per 10 seconds. Fair enough, the problem still occured but after just 1 hour. Thus it seems as if I have an issue with log space or log rotation. Can someone assist me with how to solve this?

I started to look into the `journald.conf` file and the content looks like this.

```
[Journal]
#Storage=auto
#Compress=yes
#Seal=yes
#SplitMode=uid
#SyncIntervalSec=5m
#RateLimitInterval=30s
#RateLimitBurst=1000
#SystemMaxUse=
#SystemKeepFree=
#SystemMaxFileSize=
#RuntimeMaxUse=
#RuntimeKeepFree=
#RuntimeMaxFileSize=
#MaxRetentionSec=
#MaxFileSec=1month
#ForwardToSyslog=yes
#ForwardToKMsg=no
#ForwardToConsole=no
#ForwardToWall=yes
#TTYPath=/dev/console
#MaxLevelStore=debug
#MaxLevelSyslog=debug
#MaxLevelKMsg=notice
#MaxLevelConsole=info
#MaxLevelWall=emerg
#LineMax=48K
```

I tried changing the content as below and then ran `sudo systemctl restart systemd-journald.service` without any success.

```
[Journal]
#Storage=auto
#Compress=yes
#Seal=yes
#SplitMode=uid
#SyncIntervalSec=5m
#RateLimitInterval=30s
#RateLimitBurst=1000
SystemMaxUse=1G            # Increase to allow more disk space for logging
#SystemKeepFree=
#SystemMaxFileSize=
#RuntimeMaxUse=
#RuntimeKeepFree=
#RuntimeMaxFileSize=
MaxRetentionSec=1month     # Retain journal files for up to one month
MaxFileSec=1week           # Keep individual journal files for up to one week
#ForwardToSyslog=yes
#ForwardToKMsg=no
#ForwardToConsole=no
#ForwardToWall=yes
#TTYPath=/dev/console
#MaxLevelStore=debug
#MaxLevelSyslog=debug
#MaxLevelKMsg=notice
#MaxLevelConsole=info
#MaxLevelWall=emerg
#LineMax=48K
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 2):

I had a similar problem where my service log where suppressed due to the amount of messages received inside the RateLimitInterval window. But if it's always exactly 6 hours... quite weird.
Could it be that there are RateLimitInterval / RateLimitBurst misconfigured somewhere? Did you notice any suppression message inside your syslog/journal? Something like `systemd-journal[xxxx]: Suppressed <number> messages from <your_service>.`?
It's weird, because I think your default values for those parameters are good and don't match your issue... Maybe your service provides rate limits for itself through `LogRateLimitIntervalSec=` and/or `LogRateLimitBurst=` ? Because in such case, those values override the settings specified in journald conf.
In case you see the suppression message, you could try to set

```
RateLimitInterval=0s
RateLimitBurst=0
```

to fully disabled them (just for debugging: then you should tune it), and maybe you can also increase the size of

```
RuntimeMaxUse
```

and, in case you think that the default one eighth of the values configured with SystemMaxUse and RuntimeMaxUse isn't enough, you can also increase

```
SystemMaxFileSize
RuntimeMaxFileSize
```

(ref. https://www.freedesktop.org/software/systemd/man/latest/journald.conf.html)

Comment: The question is not on-topic for Stack Overflow as defined in the [help]. Please don't answer such questions; instead, you should flag them for attention and they will be closed or migrated appropriately.